# hadoop exception type mismatch in wordcount program

Tags: java, hadoop

I am new and try to run my first hadoop program. and I am facing some problem when I execute my wordcount job in hadoop.

**WordCount.java**

```
package hdp;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool; 
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;

public class WordCount extends Configured implements Tool{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("application starting ....");
        int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new WordCount(), args);
        System.out.println(exitCode);
    }

    @Override
    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length < 2) {
            System.out.println("Plz enter input and output directory properly... ");
            return -1;
        }
        JobConf conf = new JobConf(WordCount.class);
        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

        conf.setMapperClass(WordMapper.class);
        conf.setReducerClass(WordReducer.class);

        conf.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        conf.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);

        conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        JobClient.runJob(conf);
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Configuration getConf() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setConf(Configuration arg0) {

    }   
}
```

**WordMapper.java**
    package hdp;

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;

public class WordMapper extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

    @Override
    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> collect, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
        String str = value.toString();
        for (String s : str.split(" ")) {
            if (s.length() > 0) {
                collect.collect(new Text(s), new IntWritable(1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**WordReducer**

```
package hdp;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator; 
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable; 
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase; 
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector; 
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;

public class WordReducer extends MapReduceBase implements Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable>  {

    @Override
    public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<IntWritable> values, OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter) throws IOException {
        int count = 0;
        while (values.hasNext()) {
            IntWritable intWritable = values.next();
            count += intWritable.get();
        }
        output.collect(key, new IntWritable(count));
    }
}
```

When I run my program then I get following error message.

> 16/12/23 00:22:41 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1482432671993_0001_m_000001_1, Status : FAILED
>   Error: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable, received org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:1072)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$OldOutputCollector.collect(MapTask.java:610)
>       at hdp.WordMapper.map(WordMapper.java:19)
>       at hdp.WordMapper.map(WordMapper.java:1)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
>   16/12/23 00:22:47 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1482432671993_0001_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
>   Error: java.io.IOException: Type mismatch in key from map: expected org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable, received org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.collect(MapTask.java:1072)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$OldOutputCollector.collect(MapTask.java:610)
>       at hdp.WordMapper.map(WordMapper.java:19)
>       at hdp.WordMapper.map(WordMapper.java:1)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)

Please tell me where i was wrong and what kind of changes i require. Either in **WordCount.java** or **WordReducer** or in **WordMapper.java**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You accidentally set the output key class twice:

```
conf.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
```

Should become

```
conf.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
```

Comment: Thanks dear. After your suggestion finally i am able to run my first hadoop program thanks alot dear.